# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements (iPhone build)

Tags: iphone, build, app-store, distribution

Ok I'm no rookie to this stuff. I know what I'm doing, so please dont take me through the basics. I updated Xcode to the newest version the other day, and now every new project and saved projects from the past that HAVE succesfully been built using its own distribution certificate are no longer succeeding with the following error:

The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016).

This is happening to ALL my apps! I have six of them, and all of them have never had problems with their certificates, but now I'm getting this error! I'm not even making adhoc builds, so Im not using entitlements, nor is it specified in the code signing entitlements box. That box is blank. Ive tried everything, this is definitely an Xcode issue with updating.

Please help this is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, but maybe try deleting all of your provisioning profiles from Xcode and all of your devices, then download them again from the provisioning portal and reinstall them on everything? I ended up doing that anyway when I upgraded.

Comment: Ok now Im getting a 'valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found'

Comment: Make sure that you delete/install them not only in xcode but on the devices too. That sounds like the error you get when the profiles aren't installed on the device, or if the profiles were generated without the device's UDID

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had "code signing" line in my targets and project build settings. Despite it was empty it was still giving me this error, until I deleted it completely in targets and partially in project. So that is what I did:

In Xcode 4.2 I went to my PROJECT\Build Settings found that line "code signing", clicked on it and in Entitlements deleted all lines (they were empty but still there!), so Entitlements disappeared.

I put in "code signing identity":don't code sign

"debug":don't code sign

"Any iOS SDK": choose your provisions here, I used automatic, worked fine

"release":don't code sign

"Any iOS SDK": same as above

Then I went to TARGETS\Build Settings, found the line "code signing" and deleted everything under it so it disappeared from targets.

Now I could build onto the device, not only in simulator.
Hope it helps somebody.
B

Comment: Yon cannot. XCode comes out with "code sign required".

Comment: @loretoparisi: you still using xcode4.2? it may not apply now 4 years later.