# Xcode 6 invalid entitlements in my project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, entitlements

I want to distribute my app, but when I run it it shows me message:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I already watch my distribution account  and Capabilities in `Xcode` and
entitlements in them are the same. In what can be problem?

Answer (score 2):

I also get this exception few times when I did something with provisioning profiles or capabilities, In my case its always in iCloudkit (xcode 6) issue, for some reason in app id (if you check in developer center) it assigned invalid or unwanted icloud containers to the app id. So i remove them and only added one correct  container to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, You will find many questions here with the same issue, check this question for the approved answer [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements (iPhone build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930104/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-iphone-build)

For me, I didn't do this. I tested the app on the device using the development certificate and the ad-hoc one, Then submitted it using the disruption certificate after making sure that there is nothing wrong with my certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check your Bundle ID value in both your .plist file *and also here*:

[image]

(This really is the most developer-unfriendly environment in use in 2016...)